# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some JS code that tried to append the JS file into header, but I have an error message on chrome `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` and get different error on safari `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'. Expected ']' to end a subscript expression.`, my code

```
var js =  $('<script />',
                        {
                            src         : 'scripts/contentStrings/content.js',
                            type        : 'text/javascript',
                            language    : 'javascript'
                        })

            js.appendTo("head") <-- the error from
```

If I check on header the script is append to header.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edited** :

Here is the inside of content.js

```
var sponsor = {}

sponsor["containerSize"]    = [[78,60] , 60 , [7,17.3] , [19,16]];


sponsor["imageBackground"]  = [[78,60] , 60 , [7,17.3] , [19,16]];


sponsor["contentLong]"      =   "<div id='contentGroup'>Long content</div>";

sponsor["contentShort"]     =  "<article style='font-size:10px !important'>Some short article</article>";
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the error from this snippet and not from `content.js`? What line numer does the error message contain?

Comment: @Bergi, yes you are right, I just tried to delete all the content on content.js and I'm not getting that error message again, but I dont know where is the actual error come from my content.js, please have a look of my edited question, I add the code inside of my content.js, if you can help me to find the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick spot:

> ```
> sponsor["contentLong]"
> ```

is "missing" the closing bracket.

Comment: Ahhh that's it, you all right, what a silly me, I even not see that error, thanks :D